# Is it possible to pay the remaining monthly payments of a mortgage instead of cancelling the mortgage and paying the early repayment fee?

Tags: united-kingdom, mortgage

I would like to know generally about paying off a mortgage when selling a property.

If a mortgaged property is sold, is it possible to pay the remaining monthly payments of a mortgage instead of cancelling the mortgage and paying the early repayment fee?

Edit:
Thanks for the answers. I had meant if there was, say, 25 years left on the capital-repayment mortgage but only, say, three months left of the fixed-rate five-year term.

Comment: This varies substantially depending on where you are. A location tag might be helpful.

Comment: Have you even calculated your total combined monthly payments to see how it would differ from the prescribed penalty of prepayment? I would be shocked if this would be cheaper for you, unless you are in a jurisdiction that completely lacks consumer protection for mortgages.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I could see a case for keeping up the monthly payments until the end of a penalty period, then paying off the rest.  I have certainly had mortgages in the UK where the early repayment penalty, which stopped at the end of a discounted rate, did so abruptly from quite a high level.

Comment: While it doesn't answer your question, you should also look into the possibility of transferring the mortgage to a new property. Also location-specific but in some countries there are significant overhead/registration costs for mortgages that make a transfer much more interesting. I'd say paying an existing mortgage off early in this financial climate is a bad idea for most scenarios.

Comment: Can you say what difference you see between paying the remaining monthly payments of a mortgage and cancelling the mortgage and paying the early repayment fee?

Comment: Does your jurisdiction have the concept of buying a property subject to the old loan?  I've done that (Santa Cruz, CA) before where the buyer couldn't get a loan, so we just handed over my loan to the new buyer.  In theory the bank can try to force the buyer to get a new loan; in practice, they didn't do anything at all, just continued to accept payments from the new owner.

Comment: @010110001000, maybe you should clarify what you meant with "pay the remaining monthly payments": pay the remaining amount at once (as I understood it) or continue paying until the contract is fulfilled and the loan is paid off (as others seem to understand it)?

Comment: +1 for Lilienthal's comment. If you need a mortgage in Q3 2022 in the UK and are in a position where you may have a prepayment penalty that strongly suggests you are in a fixed rate deal. That fixed rate deal is probably at a much better rate than a new mortgage would be at this time. If you do need funding going forwards, see if you can transfer the mortgage.

Comment: If your property is used as a security in the mortgage contract (which it usually is in most locales), you cannot sell the property without also doing something about the mortgage.

Comment: Editing to add [tag:united-kingdom] and providing crucial information has made most existing answers irrelevant :/ @010110001000 please put changes to the question *in the question* not in the edit summary!

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin The difference is that, if say, there are 3 remaining payments of £700 per month to make on the five-year fixed-rate term, this would come to £2,100, whereas the alternative is not paying these last three payments and instead paying the early repayment fee, which could come to more than £2,100.

Comment: You seem to be suggesting "cancel the mortgage and pay the early repayment fee" might let you off the rest of your monthly payments? Did I miss something?

Comment: Okay, I'll put some figures to this. Take the following example: I have £200 k balance on my capital-repayment mortgage, with 25 years remaining before it is all paid off. Let's say that, almost five years ago, I fixed my interest rate on a five-year deal. That five-year deal comes to an end in 3 months. There is an early repayment fee of 5 % of the mortgage balance if I pay of the entire mortgage while I am still in this five-year deal. If I sell the house now, instead of using the funds to pay off the mortgage immediately (and incur the 5 % early repayment fee), can I give the...

Comment: ...mortgage lender the funds to clear what the balance would be were I to continue to make those last three monthly payments on the five-year deal? So, let's say that, at the point that the five-year deal comes to an end, the balance would have been £198,800, with the last three payments being £800 each (an average of £400 of which paying off the capital on the mortgage). Then, at the point of selling the house, could I pay the mortgage lender the £198,800 + 3 x £800 = £201,200? Instead of the £200,000 + 5 % = £210,000?

Comment: Can yo9u put those details into a simple spreadsheet, showing everyone what's really what?

Failing that, you still seem to be suggesting "cancel the mortgage and pay the early repayment fee" might let you off the rest of your monthly payments? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 24):

Short answer: Ask your bank.

In the United States, most mortgages do not have a prepayment fee. Contact the bank and ask them for the payoff amount. This should be the remaining principal plus interest for the partial month since your last payment, and that's all.

If your mortgage does have a prepayment penalty, it will be substantially less than the sum of the interest payments on all future payments. Like if you have 50 payments left, then even with a prepayment penalty the payoff amount should be substantially less than 50 times your monthly payment. You don't want to do what you're suggesting. It would cost you a lot of money. The bank might cheerfully agree to it to get more of your money, or they might honestly tell you that you can pay off the loan for a lot less than that.

So really, just call the bank and ask for the "payoff amount" on the mortgage and they'll tell you what it is.

If you have a realtor or lawyer or some other professional managing the closing, at closing they will take the payment from the buyer, pay off your mortgage, pay off any other transaction costs, like realtor fees and taxes and unpaid utilities, and then give you whatever is left.

Comment: Upvoted. I have no idea how high prepayment penalties are if they are imposed but in the last few years mortgages with annual interest as low as around 1% were given out. With such a mortgage a prepayment penalty of say 5% of the remaining principle might be enough to make it worthwhile to continue paying the mortgage.

Comment: I live in a country with an abusively powerful bank lobby where repayment fees are ubiquitous, and even here they don't apply in the event of a normal sale to an independent third party.

Comment: @quarague If the prepayment penalty is 5%, and that flat rate applies at any time during the loan, then yes, paying off early in the last 5 years of the loan would cost you more. But I've never heard of a prepayment penalty that worked that way. In the US they normally either, (a) apply only during the first few years of a loan, or (b) are a percentage of the remaining interest payments. Any loan contract I've ever seen, you ALWAYS save money by paying the loan off early. I did a brief search to find what common terms for prepayment penalties in the UK are and couldn't find anything. ...

Comment: ... Maybe in the UK there are circumstances where the prepayment penalty would come to more than paying off the loan on the regular schedule. So sure, ask the bank what the payoff amount is. If it actually comes to more than the total of remaining payments, then I guess the OP's idea would be a viable plan. Frankly I doubt this would be the case, but I've never gotten a loan in the UK, so I can't swear to it.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. My question related to the UK and when coming to the end of a fixed-rate term (e.g. 3 months left of a 5-year term), but not coming to the end of the full mortgage term (e.g. 25 years left).

Answer (score 7):

> If a mortgaged property is sold, is it possible to pay the remaining
> monthly payments of a mortgage instead of cancelling the mortgage and
> paying the early repayment fee?

When you get a mortgage the lender is on the title/deed and the paperwork is filed with the local government. The paperwork you sign puts a lien on the property. If you fail to pay the mortgage the lender can seize the property, and sell it to get their money back. The house/property is the collateral for the loan.

Under you scenario one of the following would have to happen:

- the new owner would be OK if your lender seized the house when you missed a few payments. They would need to put this in writing. Their lender would also have to agree to this.

or

- your lender would have to agree to sue you in court to get the rest of their money if you missed a few payments. They would have to put this in writing.

You will probably find a document within the papers you signed that says the money is due on sale of the property.

Paying the balance you owe, will be the only way your lender will agree to releasing the mortgage.

Comment: Option 3: pay all the remaining monthly payments immediately (which is how I parsed the question the first time around)

Comment: I can't imagine a lender agreeing to scenario 1 or 2.  I also can't imagine a buyer agreeing to scenario 1 or 2.

Comment: Though there likely would be a significant cost difference between what's currently owed on the mortgage as a payoff value, compared to what your remaining monthly payments would add up to.  If you just paid all of the monthly payment amounts at once, you'd likely be paying a ton of monthly interest unnecessarily, as most mortgage payments are set to pay off a bit of principal, and then whatever interest you've owed on the outstanding principal balance for the last month.   Look up loan amortization tables to see how that works.

Comment: The lender is not on the title/deed. The deed runs from the seller to the buyer. In addition, the buyer executes a mortgage with the lender as mortgagee. That gives the lender the right to take the property if the terms of the mortgage (or the note that it secures) are not met.

Comment: @Joshua In most jurisdictions, I expect that the penalty fees associated with early pre-payment of the mortgage would likely be capped legally to be far lower than the combined interest cost of paying the full future anticipated mortgage payments. It would be quite odd for this to ever be in the favour of the mortgagee.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon: Seen it. (Usually comes up when there's only two payments left but I've seen it from a full mortgage.)

Comment: Option 1 seems to assume that the current house owner and prospective buyer will both have mortgages on the same house. This is probably a no-go because realistically that would result in the house being underwater on the mortgage from day one. Option 2 is actually potentially viable--you could potentially get an unsecured personal loan and then use that to pay off the existing mortgage. But it depends on being able to get an unsecured loan for that amount at all and the interest rate would probably be worse (higher risk).

Comment: This really is the best answer, as it addresses the fact that if you are selling the property, you aren't going to have the option of keeping the mortgage.

Comment: @PeteBecker: That can vary with jurisdiction. The question is now tagged "United Kingdom" - in which case the lender's interest in the property _is_ registered with the property's title, at the Land Registry. In the days when paper deeds were still considered relevant, the lender would typically keep hold of the physical deeds; nowadays it tends to be all electronic.

Comment: @PeteBecker: The lender is a lienholder and that lien will be registered with the Registrar of Deeds and encumber the title.  The lender is not listed as an owner on the deed/title, but they are on it.

Comment: @BenVoigt — the **deed** runs from the seller to the buyer. Full stop. It **might** mention that there’s a mortgage, but that isn’t required and, if present, has no legal effect. The **mortgage** runs from the buyer to the lender, and that’s what creates the rights that the lender has.

Comment: @PeteBecker: The deed is a document transferring title.  The mortgage will be registered as a lien.  Title is then encumbered, preventing a sale from taking place without consent of the lienholder.  It's true that legally, the sale is forbidden whether the lien is registered or not, but placing it on the documentation of title is a big part of how that legal encumbrance is practically enforced.

Comment: @BenVoigt -- re: "preventing a sale from taking place without consent of the lienholdeer" -- since this is degenerating into hypertechnical trivia, I'll just point out consent of the mortgage holder is not required; what is required is satisfying the terms of the mortgage. And, by the way, mortgages can be assumable, i.e., they allow sale of the underlying property without paying off the mortgage; it becomes an obligation of the new owner.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson But no one even mentionned the option of keeping the mortgage. The question was only to pay the outstanding payments at once vs. cancelling with repayment fee.

Comment: @glglgl That's nonsensical, though I can now see that it is what the question is asking.  I would think that only in very few circumstances will a prepayment fee be larger than paying all of the potential interest.

Answer (score 4):

The remaining monthly payments include both the remaining principal, and the interest on that principal for the remainder of the mortgage. When a mortgage has a "prepayment penalty", that means that you can end the mortgage early by paying the remaining principal, and the penalty. The penalty is charged in lieu of the remaining interest, and is smaller than that interest. It's not *on top of* the interest. Basically, it's a compromise between paying just the principal versus paying the principal plus the remaining interest. If you pay the remaining monthly payments, then you will have paid all the money you still owe to the bank, so you are free to do that. However, that will be more expensive than just paying the principal plus penalty.

Comment: In order for it to be worthwhile for a lender to issue a loan, the lender will generally have to know that it will receive some compensation no matter how quickly the loan is paid off.  This may take the form of upfront fees which would increase the borrower's cost for the loan even if carried to term, or prepayment penalty which would essentially behave as an originating fee that gets gradually retroactively refunded over the lifetime of the loan and would only need to actually be paid if the loan is terminated before the fee has been fully refunded.

Answer (score 3):

You need to read the terms of your mortgage and call your lender to verify your understanding of the terms. However, I offer some generalizations below:

Most mortgages have no penalty for early payment. You pay off the balance (everything except interest) and that's it. The lender doesn't care if it's paid off because you worked 70 hours a week for three years or sold the home. I pay $200/month extra against the principal so my 30-year mortgage will be paid off in about 20 years and I'll save over $30,000 in interest.

If it's paid off via house sale then your lender gets their cut and you keep the rest. There should be no situation in which you receive all of the proceeds and are trusted to give the lender their cut; that would be foolish. Technically, the lender has a lien on the house so if you sell it without their knowledge/involvement then that's likely prosecutable.

Only predatory mortgages have an early repayment fee or expect you to pay all of the interest in order resolve the debt.

You might have become confused with refinancing or recasting (re-amortizing) a mortgage; these almost always come with fees.

---

Also, you gave me a good laugh with "cancelling the mortgage"; wouldn't **that** be nice!

Comment: Technically, I don't think the lender actually owns the house.  However, they do have a lien on the house, which prevents it from being sold.

Comment: Prepayment penalties are very rare in the US, but much more common elsewhere. OP does not give their location, unfortunately.

Comment: In the UK, at least, it *is* common for mortgage providers to offer products with a 'fixed rate' for a defined period e.g. the first 5 years of a 25 year mortgage). Typically one pays penalty fees for terminating the mortgage within this period; in return, the homeowner gets certainty over their repayments and is insulated from interest rate changes (which may be a good or bad thing, depending on which way the market moves).

Comment: The house does not **belong** to the lender. It belongs to the buyer, and the lender has a mortgage ("death promise") from the buyer that they will pay the loan; if they don't, the lender can **take** the property.

Comment: @PeteBecker Actually, they can only "take" the property in, by my count, 2 states in the US, that's called a "strict foreclosure". In the vast majority of states and cases, a lienholder has the right to **cause a sale** of the property. The property is sold in a public auction, the lender retains the money owed plus costs, and any surplus is returned to the borrower.

Comment: "I pay $200/month extra against the principal so my 30-year mortgage will be paid off in about 20 years and I'll save over $30,000 in interest." But don't you lose the interest you'd earn on the $200 a month you would have available to invest?

Comment: @DJohnM Have you done the math? Could you, with 100% certainty, recommend an investment to me with better ROI than the **guaranteed** savings of paying extra against my principal?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus What is so laughable about cancelling the mortgage? If everything is paid off, whether in time or early, the mortgage is cancelled.

Comment: @glglgl "[Cancel](https://www.consumerfinance.gov/ask-cfpb/how-long-do-i-have-to-rescind-when-does-the-right-of-rescission-start-en-187/)" implies that the mortgage is terminated without satisfying the debt. Debts get paid off or resolved, not cancelled. Albeit, I guess you can get a debt "cancelled" if you do favors for the mafia or something.

Comment: "You pay off the principal and that's it" isn't accurate -- did you mean to say "the balance"?

Comment: @Sneftel Nice catch, thanks

Comment: The question is tagged UK -- in UK, all if not most mortgages have an "early repayment fee".

Comment: @penelope "The UK has normalized predatory mortgages." - Learn something new every day!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus to be a bit more specific, most UK mortgages will have an initial period of fixed interest rates (the 'fix' period - usually 2-5 years), during which you are typically allowed to repay up to 10% of your mortgage penalty-free, and pay early repayment charges to anything above. This is to prevent the party borrowing the money from changing mortgage providers during the fix. After that, your interest rates go to standard variable (usually much higher) rather than fixed interest rates, and you may repay in full or take it to a different provider penalty-free (and/or take another fix).

Answer (score 2):

> If a mortgaged property is sold, is it possible to pay the remaining monthly payments of a mortgage instead of cancelling the mortgage and paying the early repayment fee?

**TL;DR:** maybe, but you probably don't want to do.

You say "the" early payment fee, but it is not necessarily the case that any such fee is applicable at all.  Some mortgages never have one in the first place.  Many that do have such a fee have it only early in the mortgage period.  The details vary with local law and custom, and with what kind of deal you make when you take out the loan.

Depending on your location, it might indeed not be possible to pay multiple regular payments early.  For example, lenders may be required by law or by policy to accept payments above the amount due in any given payment period as payments directly against principal, instead of early ordinary payments.

With adjustable-rate loans, it is impossible to pay off the remaining monthly payments (principal plus interest) sooner than the final adjustment because you don't know what the payments would be.  Paying the current payment times the number of remaining payments is not the same thing.  During most of the life of the loan, however, even the latter probably would not be to your advantage relative to paying just the outstanding principal plus any early payment penalty.  I would expect the extra interest paid almost always to exceed any penalty that otherwise would apply.

Similar applies to fixed-rate loans, though this case is simpler.  Even if it is technically possible, it is unlikely to be financially to your advantage to pay the total of the remaining monthly payments in lieu of paying just the outstanding principal plus any applicable early payment penalty, at least until very late in the loan term.

Answer (score 0):

As a more practical answer to your question…

If you are doing a “for sale by owner”, you should at some time be engaging a closing attorney, that will help you resolve any issues you have. If you have a sellers agent, they will arrange for everything, including the closing attorney, and any questions you have should be directed to the sling agent.

To answer your specific question: the closing attorney will escrow all of the closing funds from both parties and then distribute the funds as agreed.  It is impossible to believe a commercial lending institution would allow their lien to be removed without having been paid.

You may be thinking of a lease to own situation, the key to that is that it is a contract for an option to buy in the future at a calculated priced, not a current sell.  The lease holder is not an owner, can’t use the house as collateral and has no equity in the house.

Answer (score -1):

A mortgage allows the bank to force a sale of your home to get their money back if you stop paying. Obviously if they tried that after you sold your home let's just say that the next owner would be very unhappy.

It *might* be possible if your bank agrees to lose the lien on your home, which the bank *might* do if there are only a few payments left and the risk for the bank isn't too high. But I doubt that any bank would agree to that. On the other hand, early repayment fees shouldn't be high in that situation.

For a long term mortgage, say 9 years into a 25 year mortgage, not a chance.